GCC Output Symbol not Relocatable with -fPIC
On an Ubuntu 24.04, using the default GCC-13.2 compiler I compiled
a source file with -fPIC option to produce relocatable binary:
/usr/bin/c++ -v -DBPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1 -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB
-Dbpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS
-I/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
-I/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include
-fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -fPIC -o
text_segment_transformer.cpp.o -c
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp

The compiler output is as follows:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu
13.2.0-23ubuntu4'
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-13/README.Bugs
--enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2
--prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-13
--program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared
--enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/libexec
--without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib
--enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug
--enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new
--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-gnu-unique-object
--disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie
--with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release
--with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto
--enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686
--with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib
--with-tune=generic
--enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-13-uJ7kn6/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-13-uJ7kn6/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr
--enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver
--enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.0 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/cc1plus -quiet -v -I
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
-I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include -imultiarch
x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1 -D
SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -D bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS -D
NDEBUG /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -quiet -dumpbase text_segment_transformer.cpp.cpp
-dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -std=gnu++20
-version -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -fasynchronous-unwind-tables
-fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
-fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccrIb4z5.s
GNU C++20 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) version 13.2.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 13.2.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR
version 4.2.1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
 /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include
 /usr/include/c++/13
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13
 /usr/include/c++/13/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: 4e0f319cd9945d8f5a9eeeeec1481ba5
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/string:51,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/istream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/sstream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/chrono:45,
                 from /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include/spdlog/common.h:10,
                 from /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include/spdlog/spdlog.h:12,
                 from /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp:1:
In static member function ‘static constexpr _Up*
std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true,
std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_Tp*, _Tp*, _Up*) [with _Tp
= unsigned char; _Up = unsigned char; bool _IsMove = false]’,
        inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned
char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:506:30,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned
char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:533:42,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II =
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >;
_OI = unsigned char*]’ at
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:540:31,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II =
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >;
_OI = unsigned char*]’ at
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:633:7,
    inlined from ‘void bpftime::setup_syscall_tracer()’ at
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp:235:11:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:437:30: warning: ‘void*
__builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ writing
between 2 and 9223372036854775807 bytes into a region of size 0
overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  437 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘void bpftime::setup_syscall_tracer()’:
cc1plus: note: destination object is likely at address zero
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
-I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include --64 -o
text_segment_transformer.cpp.o /tmp/ccrIb4z5.s
GNU assembler version 2.42 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU
Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir'
'text_segment_transformer.cpp.'

The symbol syscall_hooker_cxx has relocation type R_X86_64_PLT32.
The same command On an Ubuntu 18.04 using a manually built
GCC-13.2 compiler causes the following output:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-13.2.0
--disable-multilib --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id
--without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls
--enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug
--enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new
--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-gnu-unique-object
--disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie
--with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release
--with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --disable-werror
--enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-tune=generic
--without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release
--build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu
--target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.2.0 (GCC)

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/cc1plus -quiet -v
-I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
-I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include -imultiarch
x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1 -D
SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -D bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS -D
NDEBUG /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp
-quiet -dumpbase text_segment_transformer.cpp.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp
-mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -std=gnu++20 -version
-fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -o /tmp/ccIXuruA.s
GNU C++20 (GCC) version 13.2.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 13.2.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version
4.2.1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version none
warning: GMP header version 6.3.0 differs from library version 6.1.2.
warning: MPFR header version 4.2.1 differs from library version 4.0.1.
warning: MPC header version 1.3.1 differs from library version 1.1.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory
"/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
 /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/backward
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: 57ec4216d92497ddefc5d01c6cd03e37
In file included from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/string:51,

                 from
/opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/ios:44,
                 from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/istream:40,
                 from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/sstream:40,
                 from /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/chrono:45,
                 from
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include/spdlog/common.h:10,
                 from
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include/spdlog/spdlog.h:12,
                 from
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp:1:
In static member function ‘static constexpr _Up*
std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true,
std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_Tp*, _Tp*, _Up*) [with _Tp
= unsigned char; _Up = unsigned char; bool _IsMove = false]’,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned
char*]’ at /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:506:30,
     inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned
char*]’ at /opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:533:42,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI)
[with bool _IsMove = false; _II =
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >;
_OI = unsigned char*]’ at
/opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:540:31,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II =
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >;
_OI = unsigned char*]’ at
/opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:633:7,
    inlined from ‘void bpftime::setup_syscall_tracer()’ at
/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/attach/text_segment_transformer/text_segment_transformer.cpp:235:11:
/opt/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:437:30:
warning: ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned
int)’ writing between 2 and 9223372036854775807 bytes into a region of
size 0 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  437 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘void bpftime::setup_syscall_tracer()’:
cc1plus: note: destination object is likely at address zero
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum
-I /home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include --64 -o
text_segment_transformer.cpp.o /tmp/ccIXuruA.s
GNU assembler version 2.30 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU
Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
COMPILER_PATH=/opt/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/opt/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BPFTIME_BUILD_WITH_LIBBPF=1' '-D'
'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'bpftime_text_segment_transformer_EXPORTS'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/build/build/FridaGum-prefix/src/FridaGum'
'-I' '/home/ahmad/Programs/bpftime/third_party/spdlog/include'
'-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-O3' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-std=gnu++20' '-fPIC'
'-o' 'text_segment_transformer.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
'-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir'
'text_segment_transformer.cpp.'

But this time the relocation type for syscall_hooker_cxx is
R_X86_64_PC32. What could be the cause of this inconsistency? Is the
latter GCC configured incorrectly (Also, the default GLIBC version
used by the former GCC is 2.39 while for the latter is 2.27)?
Any hint is appreciated.

UPDATE:
Even the default GCC in Ubuntu-18.04 (GCC 7.5.0with the -std=gnu++20 option removed) produces an unrelocatable symbol (i.e., R_X86_64_PC32)! So an incorrect configuration seems unlikely.

UPDATE2:
I generated the assembly files. The relevant portion of the code (attach/text_segment_transformer.cpp:83) is as follows:
"call syscall_hooker_cxx\n\t"

It has the same disassembly in both scenarios (Ubuntu-18.04 and Ubuntu-24.04):
call syscall_hooker_cxx

But as mentioned above, the final relocations have different types. Therefore, the assemblers seem to operate differently. Why does this happen?
NOTE THAT, clang uses callq which results in relocatable symbols in both scenarios (although it seems to be call internally if I use -masm=intel option, Link: What is callq instruction?):
callq   syscall_hooker_cxx


P.S.: The question is also asked here.

-fPIE needed as well maybe?  Just a random guess.

@JesperJuhl Still not relocatable

Could you please provide a [mre] so we can test ourselves?

@JesperJuhl Is it OK to upload the source code (290 lines) somewhere and share a link to it?

No. You should reduce the code down to the absolute minimum that still displays the problem and then post that here as part of your question, as text.

@JesperJuhl Thanks. I will try to do that. Just for more information, the source code is part of the opensource bpftime project and I have also asked the question on its github page: https://github.com/eunomia-bpf/bpftime/issues/359

You already have the compiler and assembler commands used to build the object file and you can inspect the object file for wrong relocation type. Try to isolate if the difference appears in compile step or assembly step. I suspect it could be related to "call syscall_hooker_cxx\n\t" inline assembly code.

Friendly writing tip: using bold text so frequently can be distracting, and reads as if you're shouting, or as if you're annoyed that the reader didn't notice something you already said. Comic books sometimes do this to mimic speech patterns and add drama, but other forms of writing should not.  Use bold sparingly, only for text that truly needs emphasis.

As Xellos mentioned in the comments the problem is in the inline assembly which is not written in a relocatable manner. As LIU Hao mentioned here, changing call syscall_hooker_cxx (at attach/text_segment_transformer.cpp:83)
to syscall_hooker_cxx@PLT resolves the issue.

That looks really clunky.  syscall_hooker_cxx could have __attribute__((hidden)) so you could call it directly from within the same shared library, not needing the GOT or PLT.  Or actually it doesn't need to exist at all, it's just a tailcall of a function pointer which the asm could do.  The variable could be hidden so the asm could jmpq *call_hook(%rip) to tailcall it (after restoring RBP).  Also, instead of push %rax and using %rax to jump to an absolute 64-bit address (from executable code in the zero page!), it could use %r10 or %r11 for that.

Also, after mmap(0, MAP_FIXED) of the zero page and putting some code there, it sets it to just PROT_EXEC without READ or WRITE, claiming that restores zero-page behaviour.  But x86-64 can't have exec without read, so NULL deref will only fault for stores, not loads.  IDK what they're gaining from using the zero page instead of letting mmap pick an unused mapping.  Also, asm() is supported at global scope, doesn't have to be inside another function, although perhaps that's useful for shared-library reasons to have a .size directive?  GCC supports __attribute__((naked)) for x86-64

Also related: While linking the assembly object file with GCC, relocation error occurs due to errno setting re: writing PIC-compatible code in AT&T syntax.  call *syscall_hooker_cxx@GOTPCREL(%rip) would be more efficient than going through a PLT entry for it.  But that's still worse than making it hidden, or better making the function pointer hidden, and shortening the chain of jumps.

Regarding your last question

(Also, the default GLIBC version used by the former GCC is 2.39 while for the latter is 2.27)?

It's using the system version and I strongly recommend not trying to change that. Everything you build on Ubuntu will have at least the same libc.so.6 and ld-linux-x86-64.so as dependencies, including GCC and anything built using GCC (which again includes GCC :P). Every Ubuntu release comes with a specific version of GLIBC packaged as libc.so.6.
This shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't try to build on 24.04 and run it on 18.04.

Your suggestion is reasonable. But I have to build the tool (bpftime) on a rather old software stack. I installed the manually-built GCC in /opt. But currently even the default GCC looks weird (generates unrelocatable symbol)!

Sure, I'm just saying it's better to look for differences in other directions than glibc version.
